# Play Scala: How to access multiple databases with anorm and Magic[T]

Tags: database, scala, playframework, anorm

I want to access two databases in Play Scala with anorm and Magic[T], (one is H2 and another is PostgreSQL). I just don't know how to config it...

I noticed that we can set another database connection in conf/application.conf

```
db_other.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
db_other.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_other.user=root
db_other.pass=
```

However, how can I use it with Magic? 
(I read the source code of Magic but don't understand it... my am a freshman of Scala)

Anyhow, if multiple database access is impossible with Magic[T] , I wish to do it with anorm, then how can I config it?

```
var sqlQuery = SQL(          //I guess some config params should be set here, but how?
    """
      select * from Country
    """
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `play.api.db.DB` it appears you can pass in a string of the name you defined in `application.conf`.

Then use one of the methods specified here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaDatabase

```
# play.api.db.DB.class

def withConnection[A](name : scala.Predef.String)(block : scala.Function1[java.sql.Connection, A])(implicit app : play.api.Application) : A = { /* compiled code */ }
```